# In Kotlin, how to find all elements of a list which contains 0 at the end?

Tags: kotlin

The given list is:

`var list = mutableListOf(5, 700, 8, 9, 660, 53, 90, 36)`

And I really *do not know* what should I do then

`if(0 in list)
  println("in list")`

What can I add to find 0 at the **end**?

Answer (score 4):

Your list contains integers, so you want all items that are divisible by 10,  
meaning that a division with 10 will leave 0 as remainder.  
You can [filter](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter.html) the list like this:

```
val list = mutableListOf(5, 700, 8, 9, 660, 53, 90, 36)
val newList = list.filter { it % 10 == 0 }
println(newList)
```

will print

```
[700, 660, 90]
```

This creates a list `newList` containing all the items that end with `0` (are divisible by 10)

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you

Comment: You may consider to check the answer

Comment: Hi Midei! Welcome to StackOverflow! If you feel this answer has solved your problem, please consider marking it as "accepted" by clicking the ✓ next to it. This helps other people with similar problems find quick answers, and helps direct attention to other questions that still have no answers.